# 3d data lookup table in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to compare some data logs from a controller that is dependent on 3 variable vs a reference table, but I'm at a loss on how to structure it in python.

Basically, I have a system that works using 3 variables which are temperature, then a speed and a duty cycle which then indicate a value.  the parameters are sets of 2 axis tables, duty cycle vs speed, and I have a table for a few specifics temperature values, ie [-5, 0, 10, 20]

I'd like to be able to feed the 3 current condition, as my_function(temperature, speed, duty) and obtain the linearly interpolated value in for any given speed speed, duty cycle and temperature based on those tables as a way to compare the work done by my controller vs what was the desired intent, the value at the (X,Y,Z) coordinate.

Most of the guides for numpy and pandas I have found so far where usually more about computing matrices than simple lookup tables for a controller, so I have no idea where to start.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want, but it sounds like simple math operations. I suggest you think about how your operations translate into math. From there it should be pretty straightforward, as those basic mathmatical operations are easy to implement in Python.

Comment: You may want to check out scipy's [interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator).